# "async with" in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The Getting Started docs for aiohttp give the following client example:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fetch_page(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            assert response.status == 200
            return await response.read()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
    content = loop.run_until_complete(
        fetch_page(session, 'http://python.org'))
    print(content)
```

And they give the following note for Python 3.4 users:

> If you are using Python 3.4, please replace await with yield from and
>   async def with a @coroutine decorator.

If I follow these instructions I get:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return (yield from response.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        html = loop.run_until_complete(
            fetch(session, 'http://python.org'))
        print(html)
```

However, this will not run, because `async with` is not supported in Python 3.4:

```
$ python3 client.py 
  File "client.py", line 7
    async with session.get(url) as response:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I translate the `async with` statement to work with Python 3.4?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just don't use the result of `session.get()` as a context manager; use it as a coroutine directly instead. The request context manager that `session.get()` produces would normally [*release* the request](http://pythonhosted.org/aiohttp/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.release) on exit, but [so does using `response.text()`](http://pythonhosted.org/aiohttp/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.text), so you could ignore that here:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        response = yield from session.get(url)
        return (yield from response.text())
```

The request wrapper returned here doesn't have the required asynchronous methods (`__aenter__` and `__aexit__`), they omitted entirely when not using Python 3.5 (see the [relevant source code](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py#L491-L560)).

If you have more statements between the `session.get()` call and accessing the `response.text()` awaitable, you probably want to use a `try:..finally:` anyway to release the connection; the Python 3.5 release context manager also *closes* the response if an exception occurred. Because a `yield from response.release()` is needed here, this can't be encapsulated in a context manager before Python 3.4:

```
import sys

@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        response = yield from session.get(url)
        try:
            # other statements
            return (yield from response.text())
        finally:
            if sys.exc_info()[0] is not None:
                # on exceptions, close the connection altogether
                response.close()
            else:
                yield from response.release()
```

Answer (score 6):

`aiohttp`'s [examples](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/tree/master/examples) implemented using 3.4 syntax. Based on [json client example](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/client_json.py) your function would be:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        resp = yield from session.get(url)
        try:
            return (yield from resp.text())
        finally:
            yield from resp.release()
```

**Upd:**

Note that Martijn's solution would work for simple cases, but may lead to unwanted behavior in specific cases:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(5):
        response = yield from session.get(url)

        # Any actions that may lead to error:
        1/0

        return (yield from response.text())

# exception + warning "Unclosed response"
```

Besides exception you'll get also warning "Unclosed response". This may lead to connections leak in complex app. You will avoid this problem if you'll manually call `resp.release()`/`resp.close()`:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(5):
        resp = yield from session.get(url)
        try:

            # Any actions that may lead to error:
            1/0

            return (yield from resp.text())
        except Exception as e:
            # .close() on exception.
            resp.close()
            raise e
        finally:
            # .release() otherwise to return connection into free connection pool.
            # It's ok to release closed response:
            # https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L664
            yield from resp.release()

# exception only
```

I think it's better to follow official examples (and `__aexit__` [implementation](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py#L555)) and call `resp.release()`/`resp.close()` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to those examples. I had not found those.

Comment: Note that in case of an exception you generally want to *close* the response.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, you're right. I fixed code to match `_RequestContextManager.__aexit__` logic.